# How to speed up hardware detection?

Tags: motherboard, bios

My system which has an Asrock Conroe865PE motherboard takes one minute to detect its hardware. After powering it on, I have to wait 30 seconds until all the disk drives are detected (and maybe other hardware that is not reported on the console), then I hear the beep and I have to wait another 30 seconds until my OS starts booting.

How can I make my computer start booting faster?

**Note 1:** I have updated the BIOS to the latest version of [P465 BIOS](http://www.asrock.com/MB/download.asp?Model=ConRoe865PE&o=BIOS) (currently 1.70). I have tried to look over all the possible options in it and I have no seen any option to set the timeout for IDE disk detection.

**Note 2:** I have changed many hard disk drives and DVD-RW units. Even the USB ones take a long time to detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately some machines are just slow at power on.

I would start by looking in the BIOS and seeing if you have any options such as "Fast Boot" or similar.

Next, in the IDE/SATA drive section, see if there is any option to both disable all unknown/unused ports.

Lastly, see if you can take automatic off of the used drives and set it to manual or similar with the correct settings.

Hopefully this can help you.

Comment: I've tried to contact Asrock technical support and their forums and I didn't get any answer. Hopefully, I can fiddle (is there such a word in the English language?) with the BIOS settings and speed things up at least a bit.

Comment: I tried fiddling around with the BIOS settings but nothing helped. I guess I'll just have to live with it until I get a whole new computer. Your answer was accepted for "Unfortunately some machines are just slow at power on."